# Submit form after finished typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that has a total of five inputs (for user registration). I'd like to let the user know if the username they've chosen is available or not without having to click the "Submit" button.

How can I submit the form (using jQuery and AJAX) after the user has finished typing in the input field (like [Twitter](https://twitter.com/signup) does)? I know that I can submit the form on `change`, but that would submit the form on each letter that's typed, correct?

What then should I do?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post some html and your attempts as outlined in the [help] - otherwise you will likely see the question downvoted and/or closed. on change is triggered onblur

Comment: The `change` event is not triggered on every letter typed, it's triggered when the focus moves out of the field (i.e., when the user tabs or clicks elsewhere).

Answer (score 3):

use blur event for ajax call. The blur event is sent to an element when it loses focus

```
$( "#your_element_id" ).blur(function() {
alert("hello world");
});
```

Comment: on change is also triggered on blur

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `setTimeout` and the `keyup` event: [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/0bLgj2t0/)

```
// get input element
var $input = $('#userNameInput');
var inputTimeout;

function checkUserName() {
    // ajax code
    alert('request');
}

// on keyup event
$input.keyup(function(){

    // if already set
    if (inputTimeout) {

        clearTimeout(inputTimeout);
    }

    inputTimeout = setTimeout(checkUserName, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

with `jquery` use `focusout`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "input" ).focusout(function() {
      $.ajax({
       //your check here
      }).done(function() {
        alert("your username is already in use");
      });
    }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input propertychange", function () {

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: postdata,
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
           ....................
        }
    });

   });
});
```